# Can I run Laravel envoy macro in a single session?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-envoy

I am making a deploy script with Laravel Envoy, but since I'm using a SSH Key with password, the following macro asks the password for each task:

```
@macro('deploy')
 ssh
 clone
 env
 storage
 composer
 migrate
 permissions
 done
@endmacro
```

Is there a way to run this macro asking the password only once?